# SQL Query I Couln't Build (Join)

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

Sorry, for unspecific title.

I'm working with MySQL on PHP.

These are my tables:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++  
|........thread.......|  
+++++++++++++++++++++++  
|.id.|..title..|..ok..|  
+++++++++++++++++++++++  
|.45.|.baslik.|...1...|  
|.53.|.baslik.|...0...|  
|.56.|.baslik.|...1...|  
+++++++++++++++++++++++  

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
|............comment............|  
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
|.id.|..text..|.ok.|.thread_id..|  
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
|.1..|.falan..|.0..|....45......|  
|.3..|.filan..|.1..|....56......|  
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

What I need is to get all checked (ok=1) rows of "thread" table with row count providing equality of thread.id = comment.thread_id and comment.ok=1.

When I use the following query, I get all count of comment checked or unchecked.

```
select thread.*, count( comment.thread_id ) as countComment from `thread` left join `comment` on thread.id=comment.thread_id where thread.ok='1' group by thread.id
```

Output I want to get must be like following one.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
|.id.|.title..|..ok.|.commentCount.|  
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
|.45.|.baslik.|...1.|......0.......|  
|.56.|.baslik.|...1.|......1.......|  
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`LEFT JOIN`comment`ON thread.id = comment.thread_id AND comment.ok = '1'`

Answer (score 0):

```
select thread.*, sum( comment.ok = 1) as countComment 
from `thread`
left join `comment` on thread.id=comment.thread_id
where thread.ok='1'
group by thread.id
```

replace the `count` with a conditional `sum`